# How to Auto fill field from another Table in Access 2007 Depend on previous filled

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

I have 3 Tables 
[**Types**] > Its have 1 Field called **Type** .

[**Vehicles**] > Its have 2 Filed **VehicleNo** and **Type**(Lookup from the **Types** Table .

[**Diesel**] > it have many field but the mean **VehcileNo** and **Type** which i choose from the **Vehicles** Table.

when i enter a new row in Diesel i choose the **VehicleNo** then i write the **Type** again .

is there way to make it auto fill

for example

in [**Vehicles**] Table i have

**VehicleNo** = **58254**

**Type** = **Flat Traler**

when i enter a row in the **Diesel**

i choose for example the **VehicleNo 58254** and i need the **Type** Field fill automatically with the word **Flat Traler** then i enter the other Field

is that possible in access 2007?

Answer (score 0):

You want triggers in your database. Here some information about that: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_trigger

Access does not have triggers. There is a workaround using forms. You bind your tables to the form and put a VBA-code in the afterupdate-event of the textboxes for VehicleNo.

Does this help or do you need more information for the implementation?